# Firebase Firestore Database setData with Custom Model

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to print data from RealtimeDatabase to FirestoreDatabase. However, there is a problem. When I return it with for, I get the following error from time to time.

**Error:**

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

How can I do this in the shortest way without returning it with a For ?

Can I set data to database without writing [String : Any] as below? How can I do this in the shortest way? I like this method because my for operation is not working.

**Firestore:**

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).setData(
      [question.title ?? "" : [["title" : question.title ?? ""],
                               ["question" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.question})],
                               ["isQuestionImage" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.isQuestionImage})],
                               ["isSectionImage" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.isSectionImage})],
                               ["imageURL" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.imageURL})],
                               ["test" : [["sections" : [
                                  "A" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.A}),
                                  "B" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.B}),
                                  "C" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.C}),
                                  "D" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.D})
                               ]]
                               ]],
                               ["correct" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.correct})]
 
      ]], merge: true)
```

**Question Model:**

```
struct QuizContainer: Codable, Hashable {
    let allQuiz: [Quiz]?
}

struct Quiz: Codable, Hashable {
    let title: String?
    let test: [Test]?
}

struct Test: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int?
    let question: String?
    let isQuestionImage, isSectionImage: Bool?
    let imageName: String?
    let sections: Sections?
    let correct: String?
}

struct Sections: Codable, Hashable {
    let A, B, C, D: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case A = "A"
        case B = "B"
        case C = "C"
        case D = "D"
    }
}
```

**User Model:**

```
struct User: Codable {
    var uid: String
    var questions: QuizContainer?
    var wrongQuestions: [Test]?
}
```

**Function:**

```
func foo(user: User) {
        Database.database().reference().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            
            do {
                let questions = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(QuizContainer.self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")
                for question in questions.allQuiz ?? [] {
                    
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).setData(
                        [question.title ?? "" : [["title" : question.title ?? ""],
                                                 ["question" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.question})],
                                                 ["isQuestionImage" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.isQuestionImage})],
                                                 ["isSectionImage" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.isSectionImage})],
                                                 ["imageURL" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.imageURL})],
                                                 ["test" : [["sections" : [
                                                    "A" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.A}),
                                                    "B" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.B}),
                                                    "C" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.C}),
                                                    "D" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.sections?.D})
                                                 ]]
                                                 ]],
                                                 ["correct" : question.test?.compactMap({$0.correct})]
                                                 
                        ]], merge: true)
                    
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I get the following error"  Where?

Comment: Error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

Specifically this gives you access to a special setData call that looks like document("LA").setData(from: city).

You should not need the extra import anymore in Firebase v7.3+ so that's awesome! If you're still on v6 or older, you need it.

If you don't have access to this function in your code, it's because you need to import FirebaseFirestoreSwift which are special extensions for Swift prior to v7.0.

```
for value in questions.test ?? [] {
                        
                        self.user.questions?.title = selectedTest != "" ? selectedTest : selectedTest
                        self.user.questions?.test?.append(Test(id: value.id, question: value.question, isQuestionImage: value.isQuestionImage, isSectionImage: value.isSectionImage, imageURL: value.imageURL, sections: value.sections, correct: value.correct))
                        self.user.wrongQuestions = []
                    }
```